# How to read a field that is json or a xml object in Crystal Report

Tags: json, xml, crystal-reports

I have a field  that is json object.

```
SELECT json_array (json_object ('a' value           1)) j FROM DUAL.
```

> [{"a":1}]

Crystal Report considers that it is a varchar2(4000) (right Click on the field and than click onfield type)

In this example, I would like to give  orders like that:

> count({command.j})   --How many line has my tab of json. 1

and

> {command.j}[1][a]   --value of the line 1 for the field a

Is it possible and how do I do that?

A solution that works with xml suits me too.

**updated**

I've tried ExtractString({YourJsonString}, "[{""a"":", "}]").

But it doesn't work if the json has several fields or array several lines

[{"a":1,"b":2}]  -> 1,"b":2},{"a":11,"b":22

[{"a":11,"b":22}]  -> 1,"b":2},{"a":11,"b":22
Furthermore. I've said that I don't have nested json. But I would like a function that works in all cases.  I'm search for a function that's meant to handle json

Comment: In your sample, you need to Split using "},{" as delimiter. To get a particular element number, you need to first get the Nth array element. Then, use ExtractString().

Comment: In your sample, you need to Split using "},{" as delimiter. To get a particular element number, you need to first get the Nth array element. Then, use ExtractString().

I am working on a clean solution for arbitrarily complex JSON text. Can you provide a complex case with the actual results you need? 

Note that JSON has no real "lines". Line breaks are used just for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use a standard JSON path to specify the target elements, afaik, the only reasonable approach is to use a Crystal UFL (User Function Library).

You can implement your own UFL or use a 3rd-party Crystal Reports UFLs. Ken Hamady maintains a list of 3rd-party UFLs [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl).

Here is an example of using a Crystal Reports UFL to return JSON content by specifying a path:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `Split({YourJsonString}, "][")` to get an array.
The count is simply the size of the array.

To get the value for "a", use:

```
ExtractString({YourJsonString}, "[{""a"":", "}]")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But It doesn't work if there is several fields and lines. I've just said that there is no json inside json